# How do I use variable fonts with Google Fonts?

Tags: css, fonts, google-fonts, variable-fonts

Unlike traditional fonts that require a file for each weight (300, 400, 500, etc.), variable fonts allow you to access every combination of the font's weights and styles through a single (smaller) font file. This has obvious benefits for the web, and I'm trying to use the [Inter](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter) font from Google Fonts, which both Google and the designer's website claim to be a variable font.

However when selecting the font in Google Fonts I'm still required to select the individual weights that I want to use, and the generated `<link>` tag also specifies individual weights, suggesting that it's downloading each of those files:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've also noticed that it doesn't seem to come with italics, and when I try to render italics it simulates them with faux italics, which I confirmed by adding the CSS rule `font-synthesis:none`:

```
font-style: italic;
font-synthesis: none ; /* Disables faux italics and other simulated styles: 
                          if no italic style is installed, defaults to normal
```

Why is this, and how can I use the variable version of *Inter* via Google Fonts, including italics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Variable font query tuples

You need to use the appropriate [query tuples](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2) to retrieve the variable font version – otherwise google fonts will return static font-file URLs.

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:slnt,wght@-10..0,100..900
```

Notice the ".." separators defining the axes ranges.
You can check the result by opening the CSS link. If everything is correct you should see something like this:

```css
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: oblique 0deg 10deg;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcCo3FwrK3iLTcviYwY.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

(Most notably weight and style properties have multiple values like `font-weight: 100 900`).

#### Inter genuine italic vs. slanted/oblique

Inter variable provides a slant axes - allowing you to use intermediate slanting angles.
Besides, there's the "Inter Tight" (using a tighter tracking/letter-spacing) also providing an italic.
Although, there are probably more subtle differences between both "siblings" - when adding some letter-spacing to the Inter tight it is hardly distinguishable from the standard Inter.
The same applies to the slanted/oblique style in Inter compared to the italic style available in Inter Tight – you could argue whether this italic can be considered a "true" italic.

```css
/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-style: oblique 0deg 10deg;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/inter/v13/UcCo3FwrK3iLTcviYwY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter Tight';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/intertight/v7/NGSwv5HMAFg6IuGlBNMjxLsH8ag.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}


/* latin */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Inter Tight';
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 100 900;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/intertight/v7/NGSyv5HMAFg6IuGlBNMjxLsCwapkRA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Inter';
  font-size: 5vmin;
}

.slant {
  font-variation-settings: "slnt" -10;
}

.tight {
  font-family: 'Inter Tight';
  letter-spacing: 0.055em
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic
}
```

```html
<p class="">Hamburgefonstiv 1234 (Inter)</p>
<p class="tight">Hamburgefonstiv 1234 (Inter tight)</p>
<p class="slant">Hamburgefonstiv 1234 (Inter slanted/oblique)</p>
<p class="tight italic">Hamburgefonstiv 1234 (Inter tight italic)</p>
```

More about google font UI's quirks: ["Google Fonts - variable fonts not working in Windows browsers"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70201880/google-fonts-variable-fonts-not-working-in-windows-browsers/70277406#70277406)

Comment: Upvoted just for the API link alone - the `text` query looks like subsetting at the request level, which could be powerful.

Comment: My pleasure! Probably the main reason you didn't find this documentation on your own when you asked your question ... it didn't exist ... or it was overshadowed by a plethora of outdated google font api documentation that came up first in the search results. Seriously, it took Google quite some time to optimise the SEO for the latest API docs (how meta is that?). So I think it's important to point out the quirks in the Google Fonts ecosystem - without being ungrateful. E.g the current GF UI should help generate the right CSS query for VFs – a feature they boast about ... which is not the case

Answer (score 1):

Google Fonts lets you choose a non-standard value in the **Variable axes** section, but you still need to input the value/s as google serves smaller and specific files to avoid large requests, it also approximates them.

For example by picking `401` and `410` you get the exact same file as a response (the only difference is the `font-weight` in the style).

Check them:

- https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@401&display=swap
- https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@410&display=swap

[Inter](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter) seems not to be available in italics btw.

Comment: What's the variable axes section? I can't seem to find it anywhere on the Google Fonts page for Inter.

Comment: As for Inter not having italics that makes sense as to why no italic styles are displayed on that page, though it's annoying to to find such a popular font doesn't have true italics.

Answer (score 0):

Google Fonts does allow you to load a variable font in your site, not specific weights. For more info, see:

https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/using_type/loading_variable_fonts_on_the_web

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding all of your tags that should render as italic:

```
em,
i {
    font-style: normal;
    font-variation-settings: "slnt" -10;
}
```

I guess you could still call this "Faux" italics... but now it's not the browser taking a wild guess at how to render it... you're in control.

I tried to make a Stack Overflow snippet example, but it does not seem to be possible to run Google Fonts as an external library, so here's a codepen instead:

https://codepen.io/squarecandy-1472176736/pen/GRebKRY